# How do i prevent a Flutter listview from rebuilding the children when resized?

Tags: flutter

I love Flutter but I have a performance problem. Consider the following simple example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyHomePage());

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() {
    return _MyHomePageState();
  }
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  static const elements = [
    'Element 1',
    'Element 2',
    'Element 3',
    'Element 4',
    'Element 5',
    'Element 6',
    'Element 7',
    'Element 8',
    'Element 9',
    'Element 10'
  ];
  String selectedElement = elements[0];
  double listViewHeight = 200;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Simple test')),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Slider(
              value: listViewHeight,
              min: 100,
              max: 300,
              onChanged: (double newValue) => setState(() => listViewHeight = newValue),
            ),
            Text('Selected: ' + selectedElement),
            Container(
              height: listViewHeight,
              child: ListView(
                children: elements
                    .map((id) => Element(
                          id: id,
                          color: id == selectedElement ? Colors.green : Colors.lightGreen,
                          onTap: (newElement) => setState(() => selectedElement = newElement),
                        ))
                    .toList(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Element extends StatelessWidget {
  final String id;
  final Color color;
  final Function onTap;

  Element({this.id, this.color, this.onTap});

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    print('Building ' + id);
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => onTap(id),
      child: Container(
        height: 100,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(2),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        color: color,
        child: Text(id),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This works fine and everything is fluent when I use the slider to resize the listview. My real world example is much more complex. Each child in the listview is another (horizontal) listview with children containing small SVG images. Everything is fluent when scrolling inside the listviews, but it gets very jumpy when resizing the outer listview itself.

I realised that all the (visible) listview children got rebuild all the time when resizing the listview. My first thought was: This makes sense. Flutter rebuilds everything when things change. Then I realised that when scrolling the listview itself, the children are NOT rebuilt (unless another child is scrolled into view).

It is like the listview is saying: "I do not need to rebuild the children just because the scroll position changes. I just move them around". Which makes perfect sense.

Now my question of course is, how I can do the same? Like: "I don't need to rebuild the listview when moving the slider. I just resize the current listview without rebuilding it.